# hiding parse.initialize from front end in node.js project

Tags: node.js, parse-platform

I am developing a website in node.js and I am using Parse.com to handle the user registration and the Facebook users.
To handle the Facebook login with Parse, I have to use the line of code:

```
Parse.initialize(APP_ID, KEY);
```

which can be accessed by anybody by just looking at the source code of the website. 
So my question is: if somebody has access to this information, can he access the data that I stored in Parse? he would just have to create some simple query, no?
I already initialize on the server side so is there a way to tell the template(jade in my case) that Parse has been initialized by passing some kind of parameters?
Thanks

Comment: Is this code you've pasted in the jade template or the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set up ACLs and class permissions correctly in your app, then there should be no concern with handing out your JavaScript key. See this page for more information:  https://www.parse.com/questions/javascript-sdk-security